# Public mining pool account w private access

Tags: mining-pools

I have several systems available that i would like to use to mine to a pool account. The problem is that other people have access to these machines and i dont want them to get my password from the config file, log into my account on the pool server and be able to change the destination of the found coins to their wallet.

What is the best solution for this?

The two that i can think of are if there is a pool that does not require a password to contribute the hashes, or setting up my own pool server that does that but this sounds more complicated.

Comment: Update: i understand they could still change the config for each system to point to their pool, but that would be a loss of one system. If they change it at the pool, that would be a loss of all systems.

Answer (score 1):

Pools either don't use a password for mining clients, or they use a password different than the one used to log into the website and change things like the cash out address.

So you don't really need to worry about this happening. Just don't choose the same password for mining and website access, if the pool asks you to choose two passwords.

What could happen though is that they change the mining client config to mine for their pool account instead of yours.

There is also the special case of a pool or two that accept the user name as the cash out address. In those cases someone could change where your coins go simply by changing the user name in the client setup, because the user name and cash out address are in this case the same thing.

Comment: To just continue a bit, there are pools like eligius and p2pool which require just the address you want your coins to go to. Most don't check your password, or as states set a unique password for miners versus your main account password What you could do is set up an auto email notification that alerts you whenever amything happens, a restart or highjacking. Simply add in a few lines that send out an email and you're good. Make sure to both encrypt and properly password protect the miner folder